# Grub not coming up when laptop starts

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had dual booted my laptop with windows and ubuntu 14.04 and it was running fine only until my windows was infected by virus and so I had to refresh it. After refreshing when I restarted my laptop my grub failed to launch at startup. The laptop started booting windows straight. I tried repairing grub using live ubuntu and boot-repair, but nothing helped. This is the link to my last attempt to boot repair. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10325874/
However I am able to boot ubuntu manually by pressing F9 at startup and then choosing the appropriate option.
Can anyone tell how to get grub back to load up when laptop starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are describing the problem, it seems to me, that the grub is installed to another drive (partition) than the current boot drive. You just need to change the boot partition using GRUB to the appropriate partition, so you will not need to press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

For example in `gparted`, you can set the boot flag on the graphical interface.

Comment: I used gparted. It shows boot flag under /dev/sda2 which has a mount point as /boot/efi. I tried various suggestions made to change the boot partition using grub but I ended up damaging the boot configuration of windows as well. @meskobalazs can you please elaborate on your suggestion, how I should implement the method that you mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the help @meskobalazs. Your answer provided me vital leads to understand and solve the problem. I googled how to change the boot partition using GRUB to the appropriate partition and I think one of the suggested solution, I still don't know which one exactly, solved the problem.